# random sql connection can't be established issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

Our code is simple

```
using (var context = dbNewsEntities.CreateContext())
{
            CheckClient(clientId, context);

            var articles = context.GetArticlesForRSS(clientId, 0, ArchiveStartDays, false);
}
```

Randomly we get sql connection issues. I used windbg to check the SqlConnection, and indeed there are 100 (the default) connections in the pool.

However, when I use the method described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/remis_world/archive/2012/06/25/how-to-diagnose-sqlconnection-leaks.aspx) to check those connections, they are all closed. (as the _innerConnection object is System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedNeverOpened, not some methods that we were doing).

What going to happen when there are 100 closed connections in the pool? I assume c# code will just pick one other than create one. Am I right?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the exact exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, now I realised that our code is not as simple as I put there.

Turned out that there was some code hidden in another function, which wasn't closed properly.
If helps anyone, you can use:

```
SELECT 
  DBID, 
  DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
  COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
  loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
  dbid > 0 
GROUP BY 
   dbid, loginame
```

To see how how many connections in database, if your live system's exception is not properly catched, Then in windbg, you can use

```
.foreach (ex {!dumpheap -type System.Data.EntityException -short}){.echo "********************************";!pe ${ex} }
```

This will print you the exceptions and stack traces you need.